# ReactiveCocoa: flattenMap or map

Tags: objective-c, reactive-cocoa

I'm using ReactiveCocoa to develop a little app to do some local search. It looks like this:

```
    - (void)awakeFromNib {
    ...
    [[[[RACObserve(self, currentLocation) ignore:nil]
       flattenMap:^(CLLocation *newLocation) {
           return [self updateRestroomArray];
       }] deliverOn:RACScheduler.mainThreadScheduler]
     subscribeError:^(NSError *error) {
         NSLog(@"ERROR : %@", error);
     }];
     ...
}

// Store result
- (RACSignal *)updateRestroomArray
{
    return [[self searchRestroomForCoordinate:self.currentLocation.coordinate]
            doNext:^(NSArray *mapItems) {
                self.restroomArray = mapItems;
            }];
}

// local search
- (RACSignal *)searchRestroomForCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate
{
    return [RACSignal createSignal:^RACDisposable *(id<RACSubscriber> subscriber) { 
        MKCoordinateRegion searchRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coordinate, 300, 300);
        self.restroomSearchRequest.region = searchRegion;
        MKLocalSearch *localSearch = [[MKLocalSearch alloc] initWithRequest:self.restroomSearchRequest];
        [localSearch startWithCompletionHandler:^(MKLocalSearchResponse *response, NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                [subscriber sendError:error];
            } else if (0 == response.mapItems.count) {
                NSError *noResultError = [[NSError alloc] initWithDomain:@"com.gnou.emergency.search" code:100 userInfo:@{@"testKey":@"testValue"}];
                [subscriber sendError:noResultError];
            } else {
                [subscriber sendNext:response.mapItems];
            }
            [subscriber sendCompleted];
        }];       
        return [RACDisposable disposableWithBlock:^{
            [localSearch cancel];
        }];
    }];
}
```

When I use **flattenMap** in *awakeFromNib*, it works fine, I'll get the result, but when I use '**map**', *localSearch* just doesn't do the search job, why? I can't see anything need to be 'flattened'.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it,
so `updateRestroomArray` actually created a signal of signal, and if I use '-map:', `subscribeError:` in `awakeFromNib` will subscribe this signal of signal, but there is no subscriber for `searchRestroomForCoordinate:`, so it'll never do it's job